# MacOSX - Apache loading wrong php.ini?

Tags: macos, apache, configuration, webserver

I began wanting to install Laravel on my Mac. I got the terminal working correctly. 
**My problem is not in terminal.**
**My problem is with Apache.**

**I moved the php.ini file from /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/conf/php.ini to /etc/php.ini and it seems to load when I check phpinfo().**

I am installing Laravel and ran into the mcrypt problem. I have laravel running fine on my ubuntu machine. I tried everything.

phpinfo() says:

```
PHP Version 5.4.30
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php.ini
[[NO MCRYPT]]
```

That php.ini was copied from /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/conf/php.ini. This should have mCrypt enabled as it does in terminal...

```
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

But phpinfo STILL SAYS

```
PHP Version 5.4.30
```

...............

I'm running MacOSX 10.9.5

```
$ which php
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/bin/php

$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/conf
Loaded Configuration File:         /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/conf/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

$ php -i | grep mcrypt
...
mcrypt
mcrypt support => enabled
mcrypt_filter support => enabled
mcrypt.algorithms_dir => no value => no value
mcrypt.modes_dir => no value => no value

$ echo $PATH
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

... and the contents of

```
$ nano ~/.bash_profile
PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin"
export PATH
```

**What am I missing?!**

Please help...